# Not able to navigate to next item in ViewPager2 using Dpad for accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, android-viewpager2

I have a horizontal ViewPager2 with items in it. I'm not able to navigate to next item in ViewPager2 using keyboard/dpad. When the same is replaced with RecyclerView, I'm able to navigate to next items. In both the cases, when swiped with two fingers, it navigates to next item.

```
--------------
| <item> | <item> | <item> | <item> | <item> |
--------------
```

Contents in each item.

```
<ConstraintLayout android:focusable="true" android:importantForAccessibility="yes">

  <AppCompatImageView android:contentDescription="@null" android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

  <AppCompatTextView android:contentDescription="@null" android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

  <AppCompatTextView android:contentDescription="@null" android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue, as i am also struggling a lot with this issue. If you have resolved this please help me. I am not able to swipe with two fingers as well.

Comment: Unfortunately Accessibility sucks in VP2. I replaced with RV+[SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper)